# EF 6 OnModelCreating is called when I open MainWindow.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

I have an Entity Framework 6.1.3 application that uses Database First.
**The application works and I get the data I want from the database.**

*The problem is that when I open (double click) MainWindow.xaml I get this error*:

```
UnintentionalCodeFirstException: The context is being used in Code First 
mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database 
First or Model First development. This will not work correctly. To fix 
this problem do not remove the line of code that throws this exception. 
If you wish to use Database First or Model First, then make sure that 
the Entity Framework connection string is included in the app.config or 
web.config of the start-up project. If you are creating your own 
DbConnection, then make sure that it is an EntityConnection and not some 
other type of DbConnection, and that you pass it to one of the base 
DbContext constructors that take a DbConnection. To learn more about 
Code First, Database First, and Model First see the Entity Framework 
documentation here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394715
```

So EF is calling *OnModelCreating(..)*
Which it shouldn't!

The connection string from app.config:

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="AuthorBookEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/AuthorBook.csdl|res://*/AuthorBook.ssdl|res://*/AuthorBook.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=LENOVO-PC;initial catalog=BOOKS;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

All the EF code is as created by the T4 scripts.
The application is one WPF program, no dlls or anything...

What could be wrong?

Comment: Are you creating db context in MainWindow constructor?

Comment: Yes, it was (not my code to begin with...) the db context is created In the ViewModel constructor. Thank you very much, I didn't see this...

Comment: Although I don't understand why EF is calling OnModelCreating when I'm using Database First?

Comment: But why do you think that DF should not call OnModelCreating?

Comment: As I understand it is OnModelCreating called when you have Code First. And since I don't use this, OnModelCreating just  throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();

Comment: Your truth. Can not help here. Personally I'm not using EF. But I think this is VS designer "feature". Read [here](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/10/23/entity_framework_goes_codefirst_only_as_microsoft_shutters_yet_another_visual_modelling_tool/). I not read to the end but I think this is it.